# C# - Why is my dynamic label not transparent even if the parent is set?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dynamic, controls

I am writing a WinForms application. In this application I generate dynamic `Label`, `PictureBox` and `TextBox` controls.

With dragging and dropping an `Image` into the `PictureBox` , the added `TextBox` opens. With entering some text and pressing 'Enter' the following method is fired.

```
        private void tb_Tile_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            TextBox tb_Tile = sender as TextBox;
            Tile tb_Tag = tb_Tile.Tag as Tile;

            //add function that overgives the given name to the matrix i.e. GiveNameToMatrix()

            tb_Tile.Visible = false;

            Label lbl_Tile = Controls.Find("Label" + tb_Tag.X + tb_Tag.Y, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
            lbl_Tile.Visible = true;

            //find picture box by tag or sth and then make this pB the parent
            PictureBox pb_Tile = (PictureBox)gb_gridBox.Controls["Tile" + tb_Tag.X + tb_Tag.Y];
            pb_Tile.BackgroundImage = pb_Tile.Image;
            lbl_Tile.Parent = pb_Tile;
           // pb_Tile.Visible = false;
            if (pb_Tile.HasChildren)
            {
                lbl_Tile.Text = tb_Tile.Text; //parent has to be set to PictureBox
                lbl_Tile.Visible = true;
                lbl_Tile.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                lbl_Tile.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                lbl_Tile.Location = pb_Tile.Location;

                lbl_Tile.Refresh();
                pb_Tile.Refresh();

                gb_gridBox.Controls.Add(lbl_Tile);
                lbl_Tile.BringToFront();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the `Label.Text` to be displayed on the `PictureBox`. This is why I set the `PictureBox` as the parent of the `Label` and the `Label.BackColor` as Transparent. But the `Label` just disappears behind the `PictureBox`...

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this or can give me a hint to another possibility of showing Text in front of the `PictureBox`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the controls' [z-order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh9zw57z(v=vs.110).aspx)?  E.g. `lbl_Tile.BringToFront();`

Comment: Did you tried setting `gb_gridBox.Controls.SetChildIndex(lbl_tile, 0);`?

Comment: Thank you!

Yes, I used BringToFront() as you can see in one of the last lines.
And setting the child index brings the label in front of the PictureBox but it doesn't become Transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see is here:

```
lbl_Tile.Location = pb_Tile.Location;
```

The documentation for [Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

> Gets or sets the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the control **relative to the upper-left corner of its container**.

In your case the `pb_Tile` is the *container* of the `lbl_Tile`, so to achive the desired location you should use something like

```
lbl_Tile.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

Also you should remove this line

```
gb_gridBox.Controls.Add(lbl_Tile);
```

because it changes the `Parent` of the label. `parent.Controls.Add(child)` and `child.Parent = parent` do one and the same.

Comment: Good catch, i didn't notice it

Comment: with `new Point(0, 0);` my label is moving to the `gb_gridBox` Groupbox's 0,0 coordinate :-/ so the groupbox still seems to be the container

Comment: It shouldn't though, because you do `lbl_Tile.Parent = pb_Tile;`. Oops, you should remove this line `gb_gridBox.Controls.Add(lbl_Tile);` because it changes the `Parent` again.

Comment: Okay but how do I add the `lbl_Tile` then?

Comment: See the update. You don't need to add it because setting `Parent` property is adding it to the `Parent.Controls` collection. In your case, to `pb_Tile.Controls`.

Comment: this was it!! Thank you very much :-)